# Wrapping Text Properly

Tags: html, css

In this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5my25x6c/13/) I would like the text ("piece of text") to wrap straight under the text above it ("this is long") and not under the red X. Can you help, please? Been at it for a while with no good result :(

```
$('#myTd').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function () {
    this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.textContent.replace('', '<span style="color:#db1926">&#10006</span>&nbsp; this is long piece of text');
});
```

Comment: Your function seems needlessly complex. If you explain what you're doing we can probably offer simpler techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a scripting question. You need to either 1) use a table cell to contain the text so it stays aligned, or 2) use CSS to create a suitable indent:

```
padding-left: 13px;
text-indent: -22px;
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5my25x6c/19)**

Comment: Great! Works! Thanks!! One adaptation I made, to make sure more lines wrap as they should, is using a div container per line and a top margin for this div to separate lines better [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Eddy66/832mbvk3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by adding divs to the inserted text and applying the following property:

```
#image {
    float: left;
}

#text {
    width: 1000px;
    display: table-row;
}
```

It's a bit of a hacked solution with the forced width of the text, but it should force them to be rendered side by side. Here is an example fork of your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kq6aa4wh/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot  David. This works fine but Isherwoods answer is better I think.